# Jquery Mobile + Angular: Checkboxes are ignored by angular

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

Given the following:

```html
<html ng-app>
...
<script>
    function Main($scope){
      $scope.checked = function() {
        alert("This will never show!");
      };
    }
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" ng-controller="Main">
    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Sample</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <label for="mybox">Click here!</label>
    <input id="mybox" type="checkbox" ng-model="boxval" ng-change="checked()">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Checking or unchecking the box does not trigger the method call. By removing the `<label>` tag it will work fine.

I know JQuery Mobile is doing some fancy manipulation of the underlying `<input type="checkbox">` tag, but is there a simple way to trick it to activate the ng-change?

Comment: Can you post a working example somewhere like jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: JS Fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/fXmEn/11/ and, oddly, it is working there. There must be something in my local setup that is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out all I needed to do to get this to work was change the order of my javascript imports to import jQuery before Angular. Suddenly it is all magically working.

Answer (score 0):

The `ngModel` directive is required in order for `ngChange` to work.

(http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input)

Comment: Adding that made no difference. (I did have it in my original code but forgot to add it to this contrived example. I have edited it above, but the outcome is the same).