# angularjs ng-repeat and jQuery Mobile

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to use ng-repeat with jQuery mobile checkboxes.
The checkboxes looks right, but when you click them the checkbox isn't checked.

Can anyone tell me how to use ng-repeat with jQuery mobile checkboxes?

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="Status in BedStatus" data-role="controlgroup">
    <label>{{Status.Status}} 
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxx-{{Status.Status}}" id="checkboxx-{{Status.Status}}" data-mini="true" class="custom">      
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I guess you need to bind `ngChange` event. in jQM `change` event is passed to native _hidden_ checkbox once visual checkbox is clicked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961160/jquery-mobile-angular-checkboxes-are-ignored-by-angular?rq=1

Comment: If I define $scope.checked in my controller and ng-model="boxval" ng-change="checked()" to my input it doesn't change anything. Was it this you had in mind?

Comment: Honestly, I know nothing about angularjs, but I know that jQM wraps checkbox in a div and hides checkbox. Once that div is clicked, it triggers `change` event on original checkbox, accordingly it changes the visual checkbox to checked/not checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that jQuery Mobile isn't being triggered to set the selected style because it has finished its work before angular creates the elements. Every time the element changes, Angular creates it again because of the ngRepeat.

I tried binding to the onChange event of the field after ngRepeat finished writing it via a service emitting an event, but when the onChange event fired, it was still giving an error that the jQuery checkbox wasn't intialised.  Gave up trying to fix that and found a much more direct solution:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <label ng-class="{'ui-btn-active':lodge.selected}" ng-repeat-start="(lodgekey, lodge) in lodges" for="{{lodgekey}}">{{lodge.lodgetitle}}</label>
    <input ng-repeat-end id="{{lodgekey}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="lodge.selected" />
</fieldset>
```

the object for the ngRepeat is (e.g.)

```
$scope.lodge = {
    hotham:{lodgetitle:"Mt Hotham", selected: false},
    fallscreek:{lodgetitle:"Falls Creek", selected: false}
}
```

Just as easily do with an array rather than an object.

The class ui-btn-active is a jQuery Mobile class and since it wasn't being set, this uses AngularJS to do so.